# d3.js for graph analysis, highlight a node

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.js for graph analysis. I am finding the betweeness and key influencers for the nodes in graph. After the processing of nodes, i want only the resultant nodes to be highlighted by increasing their size, or making other nodes go fade..

please help...

Comment: What are you exactly asking for here?

Comment: to highlight a node...in terms of size or shade...i will run a program to find major nodes in the graph..and i want only those nodes to be highlighted... @JohanKarlsson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: 
If your nodes have two properties: name, gender. Then you make all female nodes larger than male nodes:

```
d3.select("circle").attr("r", function(d) { return d.gender=='female'?10:5; });
```

If your want to delete those male nodes, you'd better to deal with your data first and use exit() and remove() to delete those ndoes. Please refer to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter

Comment: how d3.select(selector) different from d3.select(node)? what does selector mean here?? d3.select("circle") is using selector or node??

Comment: the parameter for d3.select() can be Document node or CSS selector expression. So d3.select("circle") will select all the <circle> tag all ready exist in your HTML document. Details you can refer to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select